# How to access or reference assets from Unity's Assets folder in Android plugin library?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-typeface

I have a font that I am using to design and edit scenes in Unity. I am having an android plugin library that displays native `AlertDialog` in android. I want the dialog to display message using same font I use in Unity. I have placed that font in Unity's **Assets/Fonts** folder. I know that when font is used in any scene, it gets copied to final build apk. Now I want to access the same font and Android plugin's Java code. How can I achieve this

**Here is the Java code**

```java
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mainActivity.getResources().getAssets(), "Fonts/lobster-regular.ttf");
```

I know my path is wrong, what is the correct way of referencing font placed inside Unity's **Assets** folder from Android plugin's Java code.

Also I had tried placing font in Unity's **StreamimngAssets** folder and I was able to call that font using `createFromAsset(mainActivity.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/lobster-regular.ttf")`. But the problem is that in this method I cannot use the font in Unity Editor while editing Scenes as font is placed in **StreamingAssets** folder.

So how can I reference Font placed in **Assets** folder from android plugin's Java code?

Comment: Have you found solution?